# Multiple conditions in while loop don't work properly

Tags: php, while-loop

Why doesn't this code works properly?!

We have an infinite loop here!
I want finish the loop when we have 3 top or 3 bottom in a row(it's top and bottom of a coin actually).

```
<?php
$top = 0;
$bottom = 0;
$flipCount = 0;
while (($top < 3) || ($bottom < 3)) {
    $flip = rand(0,1);
    $flipCount ++;
    if ($flip){
        $top++;
        $bottom = 0;
        echo "<div>top</div>";
    }
    else {
        $bottom++;
        $top = 0;
        echo "<div>bottom</div>";
    }
}
echo "$flipCount flips!";
```

Comment: Condition `(($top < 3) || (bottom < 3))` is always `true`, should be `(($top < 3) && ($bottom < 3))`

Comment: write $bottom instead of bottom in while loop condition

Comment: @MahaDev i fixed it. it was a typing error.

Comment: @AliAsgari see my answer, it will work for you

Comment: @MahaDev yes it works. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you have a flip (not matter if it's previously a "top" or "bottom"), then you are resetting the other one. This is wrong. You will only need to reset it if the previous flip is different than the current flip and the total number of flips is less than 3. The condition in your loop is also wrong, it should be:

```
while (($top != 3) && ($bottom != 3))
```

Comment: As @Maha Dev said, it should be `$bottom`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$top = 0;
$bottom = 0;
$flipCount = 0;
while (($top < 3) || ($bottom < 3)) {
    $flip = rand(0,1);
    $flipCount++;
    if ($flip){
        $top++;
        $bottom = 0;
        echo "<div>top</div>";
    }
    else {
        ++$bottom;
        $top = 0;
        echo "<div>bottom</div>";
    }

    if($top > 2 || $bottom > 2){
        break;
    }
}
echo "$flipCount flips!";

> Blockquote
```